# Get password from a known key-iv-combination (RijndaelManaged in C#)

Tags: c#, rijndaelmanaged

Is it possible to "calculate" a valid password string when the Key and the IV (as strings) for a RijndaelManaged-Key are known?

Answer (score 0):

No it should not be possible. It depends which [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) 
 you use, but usually password and salt are repeatably hashed with MD5 or SHA1 so virtually impossible.